# Getting execution time of a user process in Linux

Tags: java, linux

How can I get the details of a process in Linux. I want the total execution time, memory map of a process. In this context the process will be a simple Java program. I only know the file name, not the process id. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If the process is not already running, then `time` will print total execution time. There is both a bash builtin and a standalone command of that name, with somewhat different behaviour. But as your mention of memory maps suggests an already running process, I'll concentrate on that.

You can find a process by executable using `ps -C java`. If you want to know what that java binary is running, you can do things like this to find the pid:

```
ps -C java -o pid,time,cmd | awk '/foo\.jar/{print $1,$2}' | \
while read pid time; do
    echo "PID $pid, TIME $time"
    cat /proc/$pid/maps
    echo ""
done
```

If you don't like the output format, replace the loop with something else.

Here is what this does:

- **`-C java`:** Find java processes
- **`-o pid,time,cmd`:** Print these fields
- **`/foo\.jar/`:** Only take lines containing that regular expression
- **`print $1,$2`:** Print pid and time columns
- **`/proc/$pid/maps`:** Access proc file conatining the memory map

Comment: sorry,i do not understand.is this a shell program or a single linux command

Comment: It is a small shell program which you can either write to a file and execute using `sh FILENAME` or enter directly on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you know only the program name, and not the process id, you first have to find out which processes (they can be many of them) are running that program.

You could use e.g. some of the below commands to find out, assuming the program name is `progname`:

```
ps auxw | grep progname
pidof progname
pgrep progname
```

(notice that if you are using a JVM to run some Java program the `progname` is always `java` which does not help much)

You might also use `top` or `htop`

Once you got an interesting pid, e.g. 1234, you could get more information about that process with e.g.:

```
ps -lw 1234
cat /proc/1234/status
cat /proc/1234/stat
cat /proc/1234/stack
cat /proc/1234/maps
cat /proc/1234/smaps
```

Look also in other files and directories of `/proc/1234/` such as `/proc/1234/fd/` and others.

The Linux kernel is telling information about processes thru [`/proc`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) so you should learn more about it.

Comment: actually my problem is that,i have a java program say MyProgram.java,i need to compile and execute this program.Also i want the total execution time and memory mapping of that process in any way possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm planning to use some memory profiling tools such as valgrid.